# C# GRPC intergation test only server side is generated

Tags: c#, grpc

I wanted to create an integration test for a C# GRPC service:

```
 public class DataProviderTests
{
    private const string Host = "localhost";
    private const int Port = 8013;

    private Server _server;
    private GrpcChannel _channel;

    public DataProviderTests()
    {
        _server = new Server
        {
            Services = { DataProvider.BindService(new DataProviderService()) },
            Ports = { new ServerPort(Host, Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
        };

        _server.Start();

        _channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:8013");
    }
```

And to use the client in the test:

```
 using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:8013");
 var client = new DataProvider.DataProviderClient(channel);
```

But there is no DataProviderClient in the generated code, since the GRPC server project is attached as dependency. And the DataProvider generated class is located in the server project.

I use the following settings in the test's csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\data.proto" GrpcServices="Client" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So how can I reach that I had a Client genarted in the test project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how can I reach that I had a Client genarted in the test project?

1. **Your test project should include a reference to the server project**. To do this, in Visual Studio, right-click the test project and choose `Add` -> `Reference...`. Then, from the list of possible projects, choose the server project, and then click `OK` button.
2. **Modify** the `Protobuf` item **to create** **client-side** and **server-side code** in the test project's `csproj file`. Change the GrpcServices attribute from `Client` to `Both` to do this. Here is an illustration of how the revised Protobuf item should look like:
   xml

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="Protos\data.proto" GrpcServices="Both" />
</ItemGroup>
```

By setting GrpcServices to `Both`, the `Protobuf compiler` will generate both **server-side** and **client-side code**.

3. Rebuild the solution to get the `Protobuf compiler` to produce the revised code. You should be able to utilise the resulting client-side code in your test project once the build is finished.
4. In the test code, you **can create a client object** using the generated **client code**. For example:

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:8013");
var client = new DataProvider.DataProviderClient(channel);
```

You can see that `DataProvider` is the name of the **protobuf file** (without the `.proto` extension) and `DataProviderClient` is the name of the **client-side** class that was generated by the `Protobuf compiler. This **client object** can be used to test the functionality of your service and send RPC requests to the server.

That's it! With these modifications, you ought to be able to create client-side code for use in your test project and to test your GRPC service.

Comment: May I have one more question? I would like to start GRPC server, but BindService requires  a DataProvideBase class. My DataProviderService is inherited from this base class, but it says service cannot be converted to base class.   

Services = { DataProvider.BindService(new DataProviderService()) },

Comment: @JaczuraZoltán The `BindService method` expects an implementation of the `DataProviderBase class`, which is a generated `abstract class` that provides a base implementation for your service.

Make sure that your `DataProviderService class` is inheriting from the correct base `class`, which should be named `DataProvider.DataProviderBase`.

Comment: @JaczuraZoltán 
If your `DataProviderService class` is already inheriting from `DataProvider.DataProviderBase`, then the issue might be related to the version of the gRPC libraries that you are using. Make sure that you are using the same version of `gRPC` on both the `client` and `server` side, and that they are compatible with each other.

Comment: @JaczuraZoltán all good now? :-)

Comment: Still not ok. The DataProviderService: DataProvider.DataProviderBase is implmented in the  grpc server code, but the public static grpc::ServerServiceDefinition BindService(DataProviderBase serviceImpl) generated code is in the obj folder of the integration test project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253517/discussion-between-zufar-sunagatov-and-jaczura-zoltan).

Comment: I joined the chat.

More detils: if there is the line in csproj: <Protobuf Include="..Protos\data.proto" GrpcServices="Client" />, the Client is generated but the there is the problem with BindService. If the line is misising, the BindService is Ok, and the the Client is not generated.

Comment: I would like to start the grpc server and the client to call the server functions, too. In one unit test class.